# How to disable cactus test

Tags: maven, jsfunit, cactus

Please advise how I can disable  cactus tests. The test extends ServletTestCase. Is there any annotation or configuration that I can use?

Maven is still picking them up. They are old tests that need to be disabled.

Regards,
B.

Comment: you ask about testing with maven but you don't use a maven tag in the Q but instead a JSF tag... strange

Comment: it is a jsf unit test case.

Answer (score 0):

I used the maven-surefire-plugin with the excludes option. This worked.